# Can't change rw file into eeprom on a ds28ec20

Tags: 1-wire

I try to follow this article [Writing/Reading an EEPROM chip using 1-wire bus](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67466/writing-reading-an-eeprom-chip-using-1-wire-bus) for read and write into my ds28ec20.

The datasheet of my components said the ds28ec20 is compatible in read/write acces with the ds2433.
But when I do "sudo modprobe w1" with double TAB, the mod w1_ds2433 is not present.
So I still try the command "sudo modprobe w1_ds2433" ans when I do the "lsmod" the mod w1_ds2433 is here.
But the register rw still here and don't change into a eeprom file.

PS: ask if you need more details.
PS2: excuse my bad english im french.

Comment: The answer you referenced shows a ds2431 - not a ds2433. Does that make any difference?

Comment: just because your device is `Highly Backward-Compatible to Legacy Devices (e.g., DS2433)` does not mean that the DS2433 driver is

Comment: Seamus : I don't think so, I see different tuto with others dsxxx

Comment: Jaromanda : It was my only clue for make it work,. Do you know if it's possible to download a w1_dsxx that is compatible with my component ?

Comment: The `w1_ds2433` driver looks for 0x23 family code - the `ds28ec20` has a 0x43 family code - none of the w1_ds drivers look for 0x43

Comment: @JaromandaX if they are not from the same family they are incompatible ? This means a w1_dsxx exist for every components ?

Comment: there is no w1_ds driver for 0x43 family - also `The  DS28EC20  provides  a  high  degree  of  backward  compatibility with the DS2433. Besides the different family codes, the only protocol change that is required on an existing DS2433 implementation is a lengthening of the programming duration (tPROG) from 5ms to 10ms` - so, there's timing changes too - you could try writing your own w1_ds driver given that knowledge

Comment: OK I will try to create a new w1_ds file. If I understand well I only need to change the programming duration. Do you know where I can find the comments for the w1_ds2433, it's in hexa with no comments. Thank you

Comment: no, that's not all you need to change ... the family code changes from 0x23 to 0x42, the number of pages goes from 16 to 80, the size goes from 512 to 2560, you'll need a different module alias ... that's just off the top of my head - here's the source code - https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.51/source/drivers/w1/slaves/w1_ds2433.c by the way

Comment: Ok thank for your help, i will try this!